# Limiting Threads and/or reusing threads for iterator?

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator

So let's say I have an iterator it that returns something of class CustomClass. The iterator has "many" CustomClass to go over. More over, let's say that a user inputs something that makes my program decide only 5 threads can be running at any moment by my program.

In a way, something like this is expected to happen:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 && it.hasNext(); i++) {
  new Thread(it.next()).start();
}
```

Now, again only five are allowed and there are many more elements in the iterator. But after one thread is done with its run(), I want it to call it.next() and create a new thread. BUT the problem is that it is not defined in this thread. CustomClass doesn't even have a next() method of any kind. How would I make this work out so that each thread can "access" the iterator efficiently?

Comment: If you don't want to do multiple things simultaneously, don't use threads.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: It is not that I don't want to do multiple things simultaneously, it is that I want to do it but with a limit.

For example, let's say the object in the iterator runs a method that loads a URL and from that URL also load an image to do things with it. Seeing as some people (if not many) have a weaker connection, they may desire to only simultaneously load five pages+images at a time and not twenty+ so as to be able to still, say, view videos on YouTube without interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [executors and thread pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) section in the Java tutorials. The basic idea is to queue your work, and when a thread 'becomes available' it will pick up the next piece of work and start executing it.